# How do I see if a annotation is selected with MapBox in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox

I'm trying to update my UI accordingly when a MapBox annotation is selected using swiftUI. Everything works good until I change the bool within the MapView Coordinator. Once I do, the annotations will not update.

```
struct MainView: View {


@State var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation] = []
@State var pingDetailsShown = false

    var body: some View {

        ///...

        MapView(annotations: self.$annotations, pingDetailsShown: self.$pingDetailsShown).centerCoordinate(.init(latitude: 53.460067, longitude: -114.996973)).zoomLevel(5.0)
//...
```

MapView

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

@Binding var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation]
@Binding var pingDetailsShown: Bool

private let mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MGLMapView {
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
    updateAnnotations()

}

func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self, pingDetailsShown: $pingDetailsShown)
}

private func updateAnnotations() {
    if let currentAnnotations = mapView.annotations {
        mapView.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
    }
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

Here's where I run into trouble...

```
final class Coordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    var control: MapView
    var startZoom: Double = 5.0
    @Binding var pingDetailsShown: Bool

    init(_ control: MapView, pingDetailsShown: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.control = control
        self._pingDetailsShown = pingDetailsShown
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
        print(((annotation.title ?? "") ?? ""))

        pingDetailsShown = true
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didDeselect annotationView: MGLAnnotationView) {

            pingDetailsShown = false

        }
}
```

I've tried the pingDetailsShown as not binded also, but the same issue happens, as soon as I change the pingDetailsShown value, it no longer allows the MapView annotations to be updated.

All I am trying to do is update the MainView UI when an annotation is selected, and have the annotations still refresh after.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your coordinates array and point annotations similarly to this [Annotation Views](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/annotation-views/) example, your annotations should still update successfully.

Declare your coordinates in the `didFinishLoading` method:

```swift
            let coordinates = [
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791329, longitude: -122.396906),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791591, longitude: -122.396566),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791147, longitude: -122.396009),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.790883, longitude: -122.396349),
                CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.791329, longitude: -122.396906),

            ]

            for coordinate in coordinates {
                let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
                point.coordinate = coordinate
                point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
                pointAnnotations.append(point)
            }

            mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)
```

and then in the `didSelectAnnotation` method, you can set whatever action you wish to occur when the annotation is selected:

```swift
        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
            if annotation.title == "37.791329, -122.396906" {
                mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.lightStyleURL

            } else if  annotation.title == "37.790883, -122.396349" {
                mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.darkStyleURL

            }
            pingDetailsShown = true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change updateUIView and updateAnnotations to include the current view being refreshed:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: Context) {
    updateAnnotations(uiView)
}

private func updateAnnotations(_ view: MGLMapView) {
    if let currentAnnotations = view.annotations {
        view.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
    }
    view.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```